# Joining Multiple Dataframes with Pandas with overlapping Column Names?

Tags: join, merge, pandas

I have multiple (more than 2) dataframes I would like to merge. They all share the same value column:

```
In [431]: [x.head() for x in data]
Out[431]: 
[                     AvgStatisticData
DateTime                             
2012-10-14 14:00:00         39.335996
2012-10-14 15:00:00         40.210110
2012-10-14 16:00:00         48.282816
2012-10-14 17:00:00         40.593039
2012-10-14 18:00:00         40.952014,
                      AvgStatisticData
DateTime                             
2012-10-14 14:00:00         47.854712
2012-10-14 15:00:00         55.041512
2012-10-14 16:00:00         55.488026
2012-10-14 17:00:00         51.688483
2012-10-14 18:00:00         57.916672,
                      AvgStatisticData
DateTime                             
2012-10-14 14:00:00         54.171233
2012-10-14 15:00:00         48.718387
2012-10-14 16:00:00         59.978616
2012-10-14 17:00:00         50.984514
2012-10-14 18:00:00         54.924745,
                      AvgStatisticData
DateTime                             
2012-10-14 14:00:00         65.813114
2012-10-14 15:00:00         71.397868
2012-10-14 16:00:00         76.213973
2012-10-14 17:00:00         72.729002
2012-10-14 18:00:00         73.196415,
....etc
```

I read that join can handle multiple dataframes, however I get:

```
In [432]: data[0].join(data[1:])
...
Exception: Indexes have overlapping values: ['AvgStatisticData']
```

I have tried passing `rsuffix=["%i" % (i) for i in range(len(data))]` to join and still get the same error. I can workaround this by building my `data` list in a way where the column names don't overlap, but maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
In [65]: pd.concat(data, axis=1)
Out[65]:
                     AvgStatisticData  AvgStatisticData  AvgStatisticData  AvgStatisticData
2012-10-14 14:00:00         39.335996         47.854712         54.171233         65.813114
2012-10-14 15:00:00         40.210110         55.041512         48.718387         71.397868
2012-10-14 16:00:00         48.282816         55.488026         59.978616         76.213973
2012-10-14 17:00:00         40.593039         51.688483         50.984514         72.729002
2012-10-14 18:00:00         40.952014         57.916672         54.924745         73.196415
```

Comment: What if the indexes only partially overlap?

Answer (score 5):

I would try `pandas.merge` using the `suffixes=` option.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [dt.datetime(2012,10,21) + dt.timedelta(n) for n in range(10)], 'y' : range(10)})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [dt.datetime(2012,10,21) + dt.timedelta(n) for n in range(10)], 'y' : range(10)})
df = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on='x', suffixes=['_1', '_2'])
```

I am interested to see if the experts have a more algorithmic approach to merge a list of data frames.

Comment: Desired result would be a rows joined on the DateTime index, for example the first row would be (were commas separate the columns): `2012-10-14 14:00:00, 39.335996, 47.8854712, 54.171233 ...etc`

Comment: OK, I am a little slow :). I would try `pandas.merge` instead of `join`. This should get you through the night, @KyleBrandt, but I'm interested if the pros have a cleaner solution.

Comment: Problem is that there are more than 2

Comment: Of course, this is very manual. The `pandas.concat()` solution is _much_ better -- I thought `concat` gave the duplicated column name error when `axis=1`, but I have a lot to learn. :)