# Concatenating/Merging List of Dataframes by Predefined columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following list of dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
rep1 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('Probe', ['x', 'y', 'z']), ('Gene', ['foo', 'bar', 'qux']), ('RP1',[1.00,23.22,11.12])], orient='columns')
rep2 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('Probe', ['x', 'y', 'z']), ('Gene', ['foo', 'bar', 'qux']), ('RP2',[11.33,31.25,22.12])], orient='columns')
rep3 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('Probe', ['x', 'y', 'z']), ('Gene', ['foo', 'bar', 'qux'])], orient='columns')
tmp = []
tmp.append(rep1)
tmp.append(rep2)
tmp.append(rep3)

# In actuality the DF could be more than 3.
```

Which produces:

```
In [53]: tmp
Out[53]:
[  Probe Gene    RP1
 0     x  foo   1.00
 1     y  bar  23.22
 2     z  qux  11.12,   Probe Gene    RP2
 0     x  foo  11.33
 1     y  bar  31.25
 2     z  qux  22.12,   Probe Gene
 0     x  foo
 1     y  bar
 2     z  qux]
```

What I want to do is to concatenate that list of dataframes so that it results in this:

```
  Probe Gene      RP1        RP2
0     x  foo     1.00      11.33
1     y  bar    23.22      31.25
2     z  qux    11.12      22.12
```

Note that `rep3` only contain two columns. In the process of concatenating, we hope to automatically discard it.

I tried with this code but no avail. What's the right way to do it?

```
In [57]: full_df = pd.concat(tmp,axis=1).fillna(0)

In [58]: full_df
Out[58]:
  Probe Gene    RP1 Probe Gene    RP2 Probe Gene
0     x  foo   1.00     x  foo  11.33     x  foo
1     y  bar  23.22     y  bar  31.25     y  bar
2     z  qux  11.12     z  qux  22.12     z  qux
```

Comment: Concatenating means putting them together and keeping everything.  What you're describing sounds more like joining.  Have you read [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) on joining?

Comment: @BrenBarn: Merge takes two data frame as input. But my problem is the input is *list of dataframes (2 or more)*.

Comment: You might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003769/joining-multiple-dataframes-with-pandas-with-overlapping-column-names) useful.  You could set your Probe and Gene columns as the index and then use `concat` as shown there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the *right* way to do this, but a kind-of neat way is to use [reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
In [11]: reduce(pd.merge, tmp)
Out[11]:
  Probe Gene    RP1    RP2
0     x  foo   1.00  11.33
1     y  bar  23.22  31.25
2     z  qux  11.12  22.12
```

---

This is basically equivalent to:

```
tmp[0].merge(tmp[1]).merge(tmp[2])...
```

*Note: this means it may not be as efficient as using concat if you have lots of DataFrames in tmp.*