# Merging list of DFs with alternating columns output using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following codes:

```
import pandas as pd

rep1 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('Probe', ['x', 'y', 'z']), ('Gene', ['foo', 'bar', 'qux']), ('RP1',[1.00,23.22,11.12]),('RP1',["A","B","C"])   ], orient='columns')
rep2 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('Probe', ['x', 'y', 'z']), ('Gene', ['foo', 'bar', 'qux']), ('RP2',[3.33,77.22,18.12]),('RP2',["G","I","K"])   ], orient='columns')
rep3 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('Probe', ['x', 'y', 'k']), ('Gene', ['foo', 'bar', 'kux']), ('RP3',[99.99,98.29,8.10]),('RP2',["M","P","J"]) ], orient='columns')

tmp = []
tmp.append(rep1)
tmp.append(rep2)
tmp.append(rep3)
```

Which produces the following list of data frames.

```
In [56]: tmp
Out[56]:
 [  Probe Gene    RP1 RP1
 0     x  foo   1.00   A
 1     y  bar  23.22   B
 2     z  qux  11.12   C,   Probe Gene    RP2 RP2
 0     x  foo   3.33   G
 1     y  bar  77.22   I
 2     z  qux  18.12   K,   Probe Gene    RP3 RP2
 0     x  foo  99.99   M
 1     y  bar  98.29   P
 2     k  kux   8.10   J]
```

Each of the data frames above has the following characteristics:

1. Always contain 4 columns
2. Second and last column has identical names
3. First two columns always named `Probe` and `Gene`
4. Content of `Probe` and `Gene` always appear consistently, ie.
   'x' always goes with 'foo'.

I'm trying to merge those DFs in the list so that it produces this:

```
  Probe Gene    RP1     RP2  RP3    RP1  RP2  RP3
0     x  foo   1.00    3.33  99.99    A    G   M
1     y  bar  23.22   77.22  98.29    B    I   P
2     z  qux  11.12   18.12   NA      C    K   NA
3     k  kux     NA      NA  8.10     NA   NA  J
```

I tried this code but failed:

```
In [67]: reduce(pd.merge,tmp)
MergeError: Left data columns not unique: Index([u'Probe', u'Gene', u'RP1', u'RP1'], dtype='object')
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: you should probably reference this question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/28292426/1240268

Answer (score 1):

You could dedupe the column names. Here's a kind of hacky way:

```
In [11]: list(rep1.columns[0:2]) + [rep1.columns[2] + "_value"] + [rep1.columns[2] + "_letter"]
Out[11]: ['Probe', 'Gene', 'RP1_value', 'RP1_letter']

In [12]: for rep in tmp:
   .....:     rep.columns = list(rep.columns[0:2]) + [rep.columns[2] + "_value"] + [rep.columns[2] + "_letter"]

In [13]: reduce(pd.merge,tmp)
Out[13]:
  Probe Gene  RP1_value RP1_letter  RP2_value RP2_letter  RP3_value RP3_letter
0     x  foo       1.00          A       3.33          G      99.99          M
1     y  bar      23.22          B      77.22          I      98.29          P
```

---

You also need to specify it as an outer merge (to get the NaN rows):

```
In [21]: reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, how='outer'),tmp)
Out[21]:
  Probe Gene  RP1_value RP1_letter  RP2_value RP2_letter  RP3_value RP3_letter
0     x  foo       1.00          A       3.33          G      99.99          M
1     y  bar      23.22          B      77.22          I      98.29          P
2     z  qux      11.12          C      18.12          K        NaN        NaN
3     k  kux        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN       8.10          J
```

Comment: I did wonder if there was a method to `mangle_dupe_cols` (which is a `read_csv` option)...

Comment: how can I group the `_letter` column part to the left of the DFs? That's important for me.

Comment: @pdubois by default they're ordered alphabetically, so you could prefix them instead, or  you can `.reindex_axis([...the order of the columns you want]. axis=1)`.