# How to pass keyword arguments in reduce over Pandas merge function

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following list of data frames:

```
import pandas as pd
rep1 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('Probe', ['x', 'y', 'z']), ('Gene', ['foo', 'bar', 'qux']), ('RP1',[1.00,23.22,11.12])], orient='columns')
rep2 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('Probe', ['x', 'y', 'w']), ('Gene', ['foo', 'bar', 'wux']), ('RP2',[11.33,31.25,22.12])], orient='columns')
rep3 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('Probe', ['x', 'y', 'z']), ('Gene', ['foo', 'bar', 'qux'])], orient='columns')

tmp = []
tmp.append(rep1)
tmp.append(rep2)
tmp.append(rep3)
```

With this list output:

```
In [35]: tmp
Out[35]:
[  Probe Gene    RP1
 0     x  foo   1.00
 1     y  bar  23.22
 2     z  qux  11.12,   Probe Gene    RP2
 0     x  foo  11.33
 1     y  bar  31.25
 2     w  wux  22.12,   Probe Gene
 0     x  foo
 1     y  bar
 2     z  qux]
```

Note the following:

- Each DF will contain 3 columns, but last column could have different names
- `rep3` contain no value at 3rd column we'd like to discard it automatically
- The row `w wux` only exist in `rep2`, we'd like to include that and give the value 0 for other data frame that doesn't contain it.

What I want to do is to perform outer merge so that it produce the following result:

```
  Probe Gene      RP1        RP2
0     x  foo     1.00      11.33
1     y  bar    23.22      31.25
2     z  qux    11.12      22.12
3     w  wux    22.12      0
```

I tried this but doesn't work

```
In [25]: reduce(pd.merge,how="outer",tmp)
  File "<ipython-input-25-1b2a5f2dd378>", line 1
    reduce(pd.merge,how="outer",tmp)
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+1 for functional programming style. Yay!

One way is to use `functools.partial` to partially apply the merge function.

```
import functools
outer_merge = functools.partial(pd.merge, how="outer")
reduce(outer_merge, tmp)
```

On a first try this gives:

```
In [25]: reduce(outer_merge, tmp)
Out[25]: 
  Probe Gene    RP1    RP2
0     x  foo   1.00  11.33
1     y  bar  23.22  31.25
2     z  qux  11.12    NaN
3     w  wux    NaN  22.12

[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

It reveals some inconsistencies in what you say about your desired result. You can see that there are actually two locations where the outer merge must supply a missing value, not just one.

As a last step, you can use `fillna` to put in the zero value:

```
In [26]: reduce(outer_merge, tmp).fillna(0)
Out[26]: 
  Probe Gene    RP1    RP2
0     x  foo   1.00  11.33
1     y  bar  23.22  31.25
2     z  qux  11.12   0.00
3     w  wux   0.00  22.12

[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks. You were right about inconsistency in my result. I manually hand coded it.

Comment: functional style was from this answer :p http://stackoverflow.com/a/28316859/1240268